# sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade 7 not upgraded

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade

`sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
7 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done'

The following packages have been kept back:

xorg xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-void xserver-xorg-video-dummy

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded
```

When i open `update-manager` the following comes up:

```
You don't have the required privileges to perform this action.
```

I press "Ok", this comes up:

```
the software on this computer is up to date.
However, Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS is now available (you have 16.04)
```

i press Upgrade.
Nothing happenes.

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

`lsb-release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-security multiverse main restricted universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-updates multiverse main restricted universe
```

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-security multiverse main restricted universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-updates multiverse main restricted universe
```

Comment: Try `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Post the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`—run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` then copy it to your post.

Comment: If you want to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` you have to gain superuser privilege, this can be done with `sudo`—so `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Typically, when a package does not upgrade even with `dist-upgrade` it's because the new version has a dependency which is not available. This often occurs if you try to upgrade while the mirror is in the middle of a sync, so for now just try again later.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by editing "sources.list"

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

I simply modified sources.list using `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and removed the lines that were stopping the upgrades that I found by running `apt list --upgradable`

Comment: Please add this information to your main post, this can be done by [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1138823/edit)ing it. Don't post answer as edit, therefore this post should be deleted.

Comment: Or, if the problem was solve by editing `sources.list`, explain how you modified it.

Comment: @fkraiem True, I don't understand running nano could solve the problem. The `sources.list` file he posted looks okay to me.

Comment: @Jim As I said above, the problem probably disappeared when the mirror completed its sync and all the correct dependencies were up.

Comment: i simply modified `sources.list` 
using 
`nano /etc/apt/sources.list/`and removed the lines that were stopping the upgrades that i found by running
`apt list --upgradable`